# Zoomeable Area, but swipe if no zoom-gesture

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, swipe, gesture

I would like to have an zoomeable area, but with swipe if its not a zoom-gesture (1 finger vs. 2 fingers)...

[Demo-Link](http://jsbin.com/bidojugile/1/edit?js,output)

How can I do that in my event-function? How can I mention whether it's a zoom or whether its a swipe?!

Regards
  lippoliv

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using this `jQuery` plugin: 
https://github.com/HotStudio/touchy

It has methods like `touchy-pinch` (*the user puts two fingers on the element and then either increases or decreases the distance between them.* *) and `touchy-swipe` (*the user touches the screen, then rapidly drags his or her finger(s), then stops touching the screen, all in a "flicking" or "swiping" motion.  may require up to four fingers.* *). If you don't want to use the plugin, you can just check out the implementation:

*from the code comments

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looks nice http://jsbin.com/degugitifi/1/edit?js,output but now I can't zoom the area :/

Comment: Ah ok, seems that I have to handle it myself, right? http://jsbin.com/ruyecododo/1/edit?js,output

Comment: That Plugin doesn't fix my Needs :/